# Azure CORS: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: azure, .net-core, cors, angular5, azure-blob-storage

I have a POST Call to Azure storage container(BLOB) which is returning to the following error. I also have CORS configuration on the place. Below is the method.
I'm using Angular 5 with .net core 2.1

```
  private static void ConfigureCors(ServiceProperties serviceProperties)
        {
            serviceProperties.Cors = new CorsProperties();
            serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(new CorsRule()
            {
                AllowedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
                AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Put | CorsHttpMethods.Get | CorsHttpMethods.Head | CorsHttpMethods.Post,
                AllowedOrigins = new List<string>() { "*" },
                ExposedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
                MaxAgeInSeconds = 200 
            });
        }
```

[image: CORS error when calling blob contaiter]

Answer (score -1):

Please add `PUT` in your allowed methods as [`Upload Blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) is a `PUT` operation and not `POST` operation.

```
private static void ConfigureCors(ServiceProperties serviceProperties)
        {
            serviceProperties.Cors = new CorsProperties();
            serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(new CorsRule()
            {
                AllowedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
                AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Put | CorsHttpMethods.Get | CorsHttpMethods.Head | CorsHttpMethods.Post | CorsHttpMethods.Put,
                AllowedOrigins = new List<string>() { "*" },
                ExposedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
                MaxAgeInSeconds = 200 
            });
        }
```

Comment: I changed my call to PUT but it still throwing the same error.

Comment: AzureCorseConfig.InitializeCors(storageAccount);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(bucketName);
bool iscontainerExis = await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(asset.FileName);
await  blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(asset.OpenReadStream());
var url = blockBlob.Uri;